# Image is not being displayed in chrome browser

Tags: html

I am a beginner in HTML and was trying to run a code to display image in chrome browser using "textedit" (Mac).

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<h1> Image addition </h1>

<p>  <img src=“/Users/aman.kumar/Desktop/HTML/HTMLImage/aman.jpg”>  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

However the image is not being displayed. attaching the screenshot of image in browser. Please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFqUY.png)

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and caugth the error where you are doing mistake. You need to change double quotes to `""` instead of `““` for src attribute.

*Correct Syntax:*

```
<img src="/Users/aman.kumar/Desktop/HTML/HTMLImage/aman.jpg">
```

Just copy this syntax from here and paste in your html page. you will get output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a URI scheme at the beginning like `file://` to tell the web browser to look on the hard drive instead of requesting the image from the internet.

So the `img src` should look like

```
<img src="file:///Users/aman.kumar/Desktop/HTML/HTMLImage/aman.jpg">
```

Comment: Also, at least in the sample you pasted, you are using fancy quotes `“test.jpg”`instead of the "boring" ones `"test.jpg"` you need to use for HTML. That will make it fail too.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the qoutations you used in the *img src*

> “ ”

with

> " "

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the fancy quotes use this.

```
<img src="file:///Users/aman.kumar/Desktop/HTML/HTMLImage/aman.jpg" alt="aman image">
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNkKM.png)Thank you all for your comments, I tried each and every suggestions but didn't work. But accidentally tried the below mentioned code it worked.

Is it because of the gaps in /HTML Image/ and since the gaps have been filled with %20 it worked. 
What could be the reason for same?